# Change facebook app profile page

Tags: facebook, profile

I have a facebook application and when it posts to a users stream it shows the application name and clicking that directs the user to the applications profile page. Is it possible to change this link to another page or set the application profile page to load another page?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about changing the link but you can make one page automatically load another page.

See an example on our fan page here: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Premier-League-Prophet/193957803989227

When you visit this page it automatically redirects to our app profile page instead at http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=105260882892290

1) Add the "[Static HTML: iframe tabs](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=190322544333196)" app to your page. This lets you configure any static HTML as the source for a page tab.

2) Use a quick bit of redirect code so that when the tab loads it automatically redirects the browser to where you want to go:

> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <script language="JavaScript">
>       // Redirect to chosen destination
>       top.location.href = "http://www.googl.com/";
>     </script>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

3) In the page config, set the new tab as the default tab for the page.

One small limitation. The default tab setting is only respected if the user has not yet liked the page. If they have liked the page, then the wall is displayed by default. However, if you're configuring the page to auto-redirect, this shouldn't be a problem, because no visitor to the page will stay on it long enough to like it.